# check for (the absence of) `puts` in RSpec

Tags: ruby, tdd, mocking, rspec, bdd

I am using rspec for my test in a ruby project, and I want to spec that my program should not output anything when the -q option is used.  I tried:

```
Kernel.should_not_receive :puts
```

That did not result in a failed test when there was output to the console.

How do I verify the absents of text output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

puts uses $stdout internally. Due to the way it works, the easiest way to check is to simply use: `$stdout.should_not_receive(:write)`

Which checks nothing is written to stdout as expected.
Kernel.puts (as above) would only result in a failed test when it
is explictely called as such (e.g. Kernel.puts "Some text"), where
as most cases it's call in the scope of the current object.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer above is incorrect. It "works" because it doesn't receive a :write message but it might have received a :puts message.

The correct line should read:

```
$stdout.should_not_receive(:puts)
```

Also you need to make sure you put the line **before** the code that will write to STDIO. For instance:

```
it "should print a copyright message" do
  $stdout.should_receive(:puts).with(/copyright/i)
  app = ApplicationController.new(%w[project_name])
end


it "should not print an error message" do
  $stdout.should_not_receive(:puts).with(/error/i)
  app = ApplicationController.new(%w[project_name])
end
```

That's an actual working RSpec from a project

Comment: For me, expecting :write works, but expecting :puts does not.  Does your code call $stdout.puts or just puts?

Comment: Just puts, I'd NEVER write to $stdout since that's not very dynamic. Instead I would reassign $stdout, like to a stringio, so "puts" goes to what I want. Keep in mind you aren't expecting :write you are NOT expecting write. Same thing with puts. I would test to see what you are receiving by doing a positive test as well as a negative test. For instance if I say "I should not get a hat for secular gift giving day." That does not mean I didn't get a scarf.